# PHP consulta count() siempre devuelve 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy intentando hacer una consulta sencilla en `MySQL`. Resulta que quiero consultar el número de filas del campo `posicion` de una tabla según un ID.
Tengo un ID `000065` para el cual existe 1 fila, me la devuelve bien. Sin embargo luego tengo un ID `000066`para el cual existen 2 filas y me devuelve que existe 1 fila. Si la consulta la hago en `phpmyadmin` la respuesta que obtengo si es la correcta, pero al hacerlo a partir de `PHP`ocurre el error que expliqué antes y no sé que puede estar pasando con algo tan sencillo.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //Incluimos script de conexión a la base de datos
    include('conexion.php');

    //Consultamos a la base de datos el número de filas que existen para un mismo partido
    $sql = "SELECT count(posicion) FROM jugar WHERE partido_evento_idEvento = $_GET[idPartido]";
    $result = $conexion->query($sql);

    $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    //Devolvemos el valor de número de filas al cliente.
    echo $row;

    //Cerramos la conexión con la base de datos
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen se ve como para el `idEvento = 000066`el resultado es 1, cuando en realidad existen dos filas y realizando esta consulta tal cual en `phpmyadmin` el resultado para `idEvento = 000066` es 2

Comment: como en muchas otras ocasiones aqui en SO, es recomendable que revises los log. Muestra el resultado de $sql, a ver como te queda construida la consulta. Aparentemente esta bien, pero no sabemos si el idPartido es un entero (si es asi no debe ir entre comilla simple). Añade un log para errores (puedes probar un try/catch o un mysqli_error despues de ejecutar la query)

Comment: Eso, como dice el colega revisa los logs, también puedes hacer un echo $sql antes del $result para verificar que la consulta esta correcta.

Comment: Es cierto que idPartido es un entero, ya lo corregí y le quité las comillas simples, no obstante el problema sigue existiendo. Voy a revisar lo que me comentáis.

Comment: El problema está en la parte: $_GET[idPartido] Reemplazalo por: `"SELECT ... WHERE partido_evento_idEvento=".$_GET['idPartido'];`

Comment: Lamento decir que esto no ha sido exitoso, sigue ocurriendo exactamente lo mismo, la respuesta a la consulta siempre es 1 existiendo más filas, y si copio y pego la consulta en phpmyadmin sí que devuelve la consulta correctamente. No sé que hacer ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, ya he descubierto el problema. Me respondo a mí mismo por si esta respuesta pudiera servirle a alguien más. Al hacer `SELECT count()` esta devuelve una fila con el número de resultados de la consulta, es decir, siempre devolverá 1.
Para solucionarlo simplemente hay que quitar el `count()`. De esta forma quedaría así:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //Incluimos script de conexión a la base de datos
    include('conexion.php');

    //Consultamos a la base de datos el número de filas que existen para un mismo partido
    $sql = "SELECT posicion FROM jugar WHERE partido_evento_idEvento = $_GET[idPartido]";
    $result = $conexion->query($sql);

    $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    //Devolvemos el valor de número de filas al cliente.
    echo $row;

    //Cerramos la conexión con la base de datos
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: A ver, si la intención es saber **el número de registros** la solución no es quitar `count()` si no leer el valor de la columna que devuelve la consulta mediante alguno de los métodos `fetch`, no el número de filas (mediante `mysqli_num_rows`) que siempre será uno. Es preciso entender que una cosa es el **total de filas** que arroja una consulta y otra **los valores (en las columnas)** que trae esa consulta. La confusión está en ese punto.